# Get all data as list with one database request

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, lambda

I have a question about the linq/lambda in c#.
Currently I do a foreach loop on the "GetUserServerAsync" method, this cause for every entry a extra database query.

On the second method i tried to avoid the query spam from the first method. The method only work for one server. How i can do it for all server in the list?

```
public async Task<UserServer> GetUserServerAsync(string serverId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  return await this.Context.UserServer
                    .Where(s => s.ServerId == serverId)
                    .Include(u => u.User)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
}

public async Task<List<UserServer>> GetUserServerAsync(IEnumerable<Server.Server> server, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  var serverIds = server.Select(x => x.ServerId).ToList();
  return await Context.UserServer
    .Where(x => serverIds.Contains(x.ServerId))
    .Include(u => u.User)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

```
public class UserServer {

  public string UserServerId { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [InverseProperty("User")]
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [InverseProperty("Server")]
  public string ServerId { get; set; }
  public Server.Server Server { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more information on what `UserServer` please?

Comment: @aiodintsov I added the UserServer class.

Comment: Looks okay to me... Can you please expand on how exactly this code is failing?  Maybe show the code that calls it and what you expect?

Comment: Based on the code that you provided, maybe you are using Entity Framework to connect to the database. Is it possible that EF would understand better that you want to do a join if you use the Join extension instead of Where... Contains?
It looks like that:
Context.UserServer
    .Join(
        serverIds,
        userServer => userServer.ServerId,
        serverId => serverId,
        (userServer, serverId) => userServer
     )
    .Include(u => u.User)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

Comment: @Rémi that Where contains clause should be translated into a simple `Where in ()` in sql. nothing fancy.

Comment: @LouisIngenthron On my list I only get one data back, but in the "server" list are more as one. 
Rémi Yes, I'm using EF with mysql database. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Rémi I tried your code and it works, but im sure it load always all data and not only the required from the variable server. On the debug mode i couldnt find any where in the sql select.

Comment: @TimoFalter Assuming you are using EF Core, that is probably correct - EF can't `Join` to a local `List` on the server side - your `Where(Contains)` should be the right approach - what is going wrong with it?

Comment: @NetMage Yea, there where work. I tried it again. Sorry for taking all the time. I already had the solution on my question. ._.